# Will a rollback in a @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW) be propagated to the outer transaction?

Tags: spring, transactions

I have a @Transactional(REQUIRED) method that invokes a @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW). The default behaviour I am seeing is the inner transaction is being rolled back, but the outer is being committed. Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is the expected behavior. The outer transaction is suspended while the inner transaction is executed. Once the inner transaction ends (whether it's a commit or rollback), the outer transaction resumes.

BTW, [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#tx-propagation-requires_new) says it:

> PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW, in contrast to PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, uses a
>   completely independent transaction for each affected transaction
>   scope. In that case, the underlying physical transactions are
>   different and hence can commit or roll back independently, with an
>   outer transaction not affected by an inner transaction's rollback
>   status.